# difference between the methods update() and dofinal() in cipher

Tags: security, cryptography, padding

I have read one article  about difference between the methods update() and dofinal() in cipher. 
 It was about what will happend if we want to encrypt 4 Bytes Array, when the block size of the cipher is for example 8 Bytes. If we call update here it will return null. My question is: what will happen if we call doFinal() with a 4 byte array to encrypt, and the buffer size is 8 bytes, how many bytes encoded data will we receive on the return?

Answer (score 1):

- `update()`: feed the data, again and again, enables you to encrypt long files, streams.
- `dofinal()`: apply the requested padding scheme to the data, if requested and necessary, then encrypt. ECB and CBC mode requires padding but CTR mode doesn't. If NOPADDING has used some libraries may [secretly pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385412/is-correct-to-use-cbc-with-nopadding-in-aes-encryption), in others you have to handle the padding yourself.

When you call, `dofinal()` with 4-byte data, if NOPADDING is not set, it will be padded and then encrypted.

From Java Doc;

- `update(byte[] input)`
  Continues a multiple-part encryption or decryption operation (depending on how this cipher was initialized), processing another data part.
- `doFinal()`
  Finishes a multiple-part encryption or decryption operation, depending on how this cipher was initialized.

Comment: and if we use for example NoPadding? will it be just encrypted and we get 4 Bytes on the return?

Comment: No, you can't. No padding means tell the cipher I'll handle the padding. Block ciphers cannot run without a full block. But really depend on the library. Some may [secretly pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385412/is-correct-to-use-cbc-with-nopadding-in-aes-encryption)

Comment: Beware that there may be implementation differences. For instance, `update` may not cache any plaintext or it may cache one block of plaintext for CTR mode. For authenticated modes such as GCM mode the authentication tag value is also generated during `doFinal`. Even weirder, during decryption GCM mode also needs to cache data and will not directly decrypt because of that tag value. For RSA the `update` methods will just cache as much data as the RSA mode can hold until you call `doFinal` when all the ciphertext is returned at once.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes these knowledge need to turn into an answer.

Comment: I am interested now more in CBC or ECB modes and exactly Nopadding. What will happen if our message is smaller than cipher block.

Comment: First of all, forget about ECB mode. It is insecure. One should use authenticated encryption as AES-GCM. As Maarten noted it really depends on the implementation.

Comment: For ECB and CBC mode with no padding it is very likely that up to one block of plaintext is cached. Once a block is full it will be encrypted / decrypted and returned. So update may return no data or one or multiple blocks of data. So does `doFinal` really, but if there is any bytes left over in the buffer (after the final processing - doFinal may accept additional input) it will throw an `IllegalBlockSizeException,` exception instead of returning zero bytes.