# What is the file size after encryption using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in java

Tags: java, android, sockets, encryption, aes

I tried to use encryption and decryption when sending files using socket. I use the `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` algorithm and first write the `IV` and then the file to the stream.

The **problem** is that the loop does not end when the file is receiving.

I think this is due to the file size and the encrypted file seems to be smaller than the original file, While I give the size of the original file to the receiver. If this hypothesis is correct, is there a way to calculate the size of the encrypted file?

**File sender**

```
            SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            byte[] iv = AES.randomNonce(16);
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);

            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(iv);
            outputStream.flush();
            inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(message.getUri());
            cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);

            long size = message.getSize();
            long written = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int count;
            int percent = 0;
            while (!isStopped && (count = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                written += count;
                int p = (int) (((float) written / (float) size) * 100);
                if (percent != p) {
                    percent = p;
                    if (onProgressListener != null) {
                        onProgressListener.onProgress(percent);
                    }
                }
            }
            cipherOutputStream.flush();
            if (onProgressListener != null) {
                onProgressListener.onEnd(null);
            }
```

**File receiver**

```
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            inputStream.read(iv);

            SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);

            cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);

            long size = message.getSize();
            long read = size;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int count;
            int percent = 0;
            while (!isStopped && read > 0 && (count = cipherInputStream.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, read))) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                read -= count;
                int p = (int) (((float) read / (float) size) * 100);
                if (percent != p) {
                    percent = p;
                    if (onProgressListener != null) {
                        onProgressListener.onProgress(100 - percent);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (onProgressListener != null) {
                onProgressListener.onEnd(Uri.fromFile(file));
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

**The improper code**

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64837519/what-is-the-file-size-after-encryption-using-aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-in-java/64838079?noredirect=1#comment114636083_64838079) by PresidentJamesK.Polk you need to close the `CipherOutputStream` in the sender side by calling the `.close()` function that calls the `doFinal()` to finalize the encryption.

**The padding size**

Although Java says `PKCS5Padding` actually it is `PKCS#7 Padding`. `PKCS#5 Padding` is defined for 8 octets, i.e. block ciphers with 64-bit block size like DES.

PKCS#7 standard is on the [rfc2315](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2315.txt) (10.3 note 2):

> For such algorithms, the method shall be to pad the input at the trailing end with k - (l mod k) octets all having value k - (l mod k), where l is the length of the input.

An octet is one byte and the `k` is the block size in bytes, and it is `16` for AES.

We need to calculate `IV_length + message_size_with_padding`

If we assume that you have `l` bytes to encrypt then the output size is

`16 + l + 16 - (l mod 16)`  therefore at most 16 byte extended due to padding.

**A sample Java code**

```java
    /**
    * A simple function to calculate the plaintext size after 
    * PKCS#7 padding is applied to the message.
    * 
    *          In Java PKCS#7 = PKCS#5
    * 
    * @param messageSize : the byte size of the plaintext
    * @return message size after the PKCS#7 padding is applied
    */
    public int paddedMessageSize( int messageSize ) {
        
        // first 16 is the prepended IV
        return ( 16 + messageSize + 16 - (messageSize % 16));
    }
```

---

**Notes**

CBC mode is vulnerable to padding oracle attacks where applicable. CBC mode provides only confidentiality. If you need integrity and authentication ( you should) either use CBC with HMAC or better use authenticated encryption modes like AES-GCM which doesn't require padding at all, however, you need to store the tag, too. If you fear the nonce reuse issue for AES-GCM then you can use AES-GCM-SIV, which is a nonce misuse resistant scheme. If you are not obligated to use AES you can prefer ChaCha20-Poly1305 which might be easier to use than AES-GCM [[1]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84357/18298)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64507126/1820553).

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete code. I have closed the `cipherOutputStream` and all other streams in my full code.

Comment: @HusseinYaqoobi you should post a minimal, verifiable, and complete code.

Comment: I tried this after several tests:`long size = message.getSize() - 16 - (message.getSize() % 16);` on the receiver and was able to get out of the loop. But the size of the decrypted file is slightly larger than the size of the original file and the encryption is not done properly.

Comment: Did you consider base64 encoding decoding?

Comment: Can you decrypt without a padding error? Could you check the last block bytes?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of an Android project. When I run this code in Android Studio, Logcat did not show me any exception. But when I run this code in Windows using Eclipse, I got this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
```

So, based on [Kelalaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820553/kelalaka)'s answer, I realized that the problem is that `cipherInputStream` and `cipherOutputStream` did not close properly. In fact, I first close `inputStream` and `outputStream`, and then cipher streams. So I closed the cipher streams first and then the other streams and now the encryption is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check for this exception.
java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Comment: Android Studio may not show it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30109848)